# Сравнение переменной и атрибута всех экземпляров класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать часть кода, связанную со сравнением значения переменной с определенным атрибутом каждого экземпляра класса и дальнейшей передачей другого атрибута экземпляра, первый атрибут которого равен переменной.

Есть некий класс `Tr`, на основе него созданы экземпляры `TDN10` и `TDN16` (на деле их больше) с атрибутами `name`,`p`. Допусти ранее получено значение (`a = 'ТДН-16'`), равное атрибуту `name` одного из экземпляров.

Нужно создать функцию, которая будет сравнивать значение `a` и значение атрибута `name` каждого экземпляра. Затем функция должна передавать значение другого атрибута экземпляра (у которого выполняется `a = name`) в стороннюю переменную (список `b`).

В итоге должно получится b = [85]

```
class Tr:
    def __init__(self, name, p):
        self.name = name
        self.p = p


TDN10 = Tr('ТДН-10', 60)
TDN16 = Tr('ТДН-16', 85)
a = 'ТДН-16'
b = []


def adding():
    if a == Tr.name:
        b.append(Tr.p)


print(b)
```

Comment: А `name` может повторяться у разных экземпляров? Я бы вообще словарь сделал, будет быстро работать. Зачем тут класс вообще непонятно, словаря достаточно.

Comment: `name` будет всегда отличаться. По поводу словаря, я человек новый, неопытный, как то не сообразил, но спасибо за совет, попробую и через словарь. Вообще, в перспективе хочу что то вроде базы данных сделать, будет что-то около 100 экземпляров нынешнего класса

Comment: Ну тогда просто словарь: `d = {'ТДН-10': 60, 'ТДН-16': 85}; print(d['ТДН-16'])`. Доступ к элементам словаря по ключу - моментальный, ничего не нужно перебирать.

Comment: Так, а если у меня 8 атрибутов (мб больше будет), просто для примера я сократил количество до 2х.

Comment: Но ключевой то атрибут, по которому будет поиск, будет один? Тогда словарь будет вида ключ:объект_с_атрибутами, ну или не объект, а можно кортеж, именованный кортеж.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно занести в список все экземпляры, и далее перебирать их, как элементы списка

```
class Tr:
    def __init__(self, name, p):
        self.name = name
        self.p = p


TDN10 = Tr('ТДН-10', 60)
TDN16 = Tr('ТДН-16', 85)
lst = [TDN10,TDN16]
a = 'ТДН-16'
b = []


def adding():
    for el in lst:
        if a == el.name:
            b.append(el.p)

adding()
print(b)
```

Comment: Спасибо, как обычно все оказалось настолько просто)

Comment: @АлександрБарташевский пожалуйста:) И не забудьте принять ответ.